# Filter the attribute value of advanced search in according to the category dropdown selector option attribute in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, mysql, php-5.4, advanced-search

I have a 6 attribute(category, length, diameter, material, package, straight)  which is assign in advance search. I want when category dropdown is change the other attribute value dropdown will be change in according to the category attached product attribute, i.e. show other five attribute(length, diameter, material, package, straight) based on the selected category product attribute only.

Answer (score 1):

My best advice would be to implement something link the admin's `SelectUpdater`. This will allow you to link two selects together so that when you change the first select the contents of the second one will also change.

What you need for this is a function that will give you the options of all the "child" selects in the following format.

```
array(
    'first_select_value1' => array(
        'second_select_value1' => 'second_select_text1',
        'second_select_value2' => 'second_select_text2',
    ),
    'first_select_value2' => array(
        'second_select_value3' => 'second_select_text3',
        'second_select_value4' => 'second_select_text4',
    )
)
```

You then need to pass this array json encoded into the `SelectUpdater` function. For this I would suggest making a copy of it in a module so that it is included in the frontend, as it is currently only in the admin section. Then the following snippet should link the two select elements.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var updater = new SelectUpdater(
        "select1", // id of first select
        "select2", // id of second select
        "none", // defaults
        "none", // defaults
        <?php echo $this->helper('some_helper')->getConfigInJsonFormat() ?>, // values in json format
        false
    );
    updater.update();
</script>
```